# How to solve issue with React updating state (using useState / setState) properly but no rerendering component?

Tags: reactjs

The following code demonstrates an issue with React that I cannot solve.

Clicking the button "Update State" triggers an update of `state` by replacing the current state (array with 3 strings) by an updated array (with 4 strings).

`strings` as well as `state` are updated properly as the console.logs show. However, the React component is not rerendered (the 4th paragraph with "String D" is not shown). What can I do to ensure that the rerendering takes place immediately after updating the component's `state` with `setState`? I thought that using the `setState` function of the `useState` hook should always trigger the rerendering process.

```
const { useState } = require('react');

let strings = [
  "String A",
  "String B",
  "String C"
]

const TestComponent = () => {
  const [ state, setState] = useState(strings);

  const click = () => {
    strings.push("String D");
    console.log(strings);
    setState(strings, console.log(state));
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      { state.map( (item) => <p>{item}</p>) }
      <button onClick={click}>Update State</button>
    </div>
  )
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

React is about immutability, so you have to avoid to mutate the array, but replace it entirely:

```
  const click = () => {
    const copy = [...strings]; //create a copy
    copy.push("String D");
    console.log(copy);
    setState(copy, console.log(state));
  }
```

An alternative syntax is this:

```
  const click = () => {
    const copy = [...strings, "String D"];
    console.log(copy);
    setState(copy, console.log(state));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
const click = () => {
setState([...strings, "String D"]);
  }
```